# Is there any interpretation for the ratio of the second derivative to the first derivative?

Tags: derivatives

Suppose we have a differentiable function $g(x)$. Let's define a function $h(x)=axg(x)$ where $a$ is a constant (this is just as an example). I want to check the convexity/concavity of function $h(x)$. Is there any interpretation for the ration of the second derivative of a function to its first derivative, that is, $\frac{g^{\prime \prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)}$? $h^{\prime \prime}(x)=a\left[x g^{\prime \prime}(x) + 2g^{\prime}(x) \right]$

Comment: As stated this seems to be two different questions mixed together. To answer the question that's explicitly asked, one interpretation of $\frac{g''(x)}{g'(x)}$ is the derivative of $\log g'(x)$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, you are right. I am wondering if $log(g^{\prime}(x)) $ has any meaningful interpretation? Based on the formula, can we say anything about the convexity of function $h(x)$?